# merging two data frames horizontally in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, duplicates, concatenation

I have two HUGE data frames, df1 has (8831 rows x 918 cols), df2 has (8831 rows x 944 cols). I am trying to merge them horizontally and avoid creating "duplicates". The titles are the same for many of the cols and the content is also the same what is different is the storage. my df1 cols are stored as int8 which is what I want to preserve.

To summarize, I want to horizontally merge df1 and df2, if the col is the same title for df1 and df2 then I want to take df1 only.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: I recommend that you take this in stages, following what you learn from the tutorials and examples.  If you get stuck, please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried to address this problem, else look for a good tutorial on Pandas and try some code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared what types of dataframe you might be working on, Here's a dataframe I myself created.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'One': [1,3,5,7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Two': [2,4,6,8]})
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(df_merged)
```

That would give you the following output.

```
   One  Two
0  1.0  NaN
1  3.0  NaN
2  5.0  NaN
3  7.0  NaN
0  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  4.0
2  NaN  6.0
3  NaN  8.0
```